# Control the way git prints file names so that they can be passed to rm?

Tags: git, rm

When I print a file from git using the command, there are edge cases:

```
git diff --no-renames --name-only
```

Edge case 1: spaces

(added `--diff-filter=D` for illustrative purposes)

```
# format 1: unquoted

$: touch 'foo bar.txt'
$: git add 'foo bar.txt'
$: git commit -m 'test'
$: rm 'foo bar.txt'

$: git diff --no-renames --name-only --diff-filter=D
foo bar.txt
```

Edge case two: special chars

```
# format 2: quoted

$: touch 'foo
bar.txt'
$: git add 'foo$\nbar.txt'
$: git commit -m "test"
$: rm foo$'\n'bar.txt

$: git diff --no-renames --name-only --diff-filter=D
'foo\nbar.txt'
```

Neither `foo bar.txt` nor `'foo\nbar.txt'` can be submitted to `rm` for deletion as-is.  And, they are inconsistent.

Is there a way to control how `git` forms the file names so that they can be removed by `rm` as is?

Comment: with the `-z` flag, e.g. `git diff --no-renames --name-only -z | while IFS= read -rd '' file; do printf '<%s>\n' "$file"; done`

Comment: Why would you want to use the output of that command with `rm`? Can't you use `git clean`?

Comment: went with the `-z` flag.

Comment: With GNU/BSD `xargs`,  something like: `git diff --no-renames --name-only -z | xargs -t0 rm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git diff --no-renames --name-only -z | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'rm -- "{}"'` is what I went with.

Answer (score 0):

Would using awk for you? escaping the quotes before and after $0 will include the name with the space in quotes.  rm should work fine with that format.

```
git diff --no-renames --name-only | awk '{system("rm \""$0"\"")}'
```

As for the second edge case, the below will work with all special characters except the newline that you used in your example:

```
git diff --no-renames --name-only | awk '{system("rm "$0)}'
```

With that said, having spaces in name is already bad practice and should be avoid because of these exact issues, having a newline control character in a name, is just adding complexity with 0 benefit, what is the use case for a new line char in a name?

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but tbh may be surprisingly complex.

Comment: I tested it and it worked.  tbh I do not understand why you want this added level of complexity with your file names?  what benefit/reason do you want newline in your file name?

Comment: It is not whether I want a newline in a file, it is whether the code is robust against all circumstances.  `-z` is the simplest, best solution and there is no need for `awk`.